# how to pass javaagent to emr spark applications?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr, profiler

I am trying to use [uber jvm profiler](https://github.com/uber-common/jvm-profiler/blob/27e4227e7fef68656c70c95c82c969ae6baf497c/README.md) to profile my spark application (spark 2.4, running on emr 5.21)

Following is my cluster configuration

```
          [
             {
                "classification": "spark-defaults",
                "properties": {
                   "spark.executor.memory": "38300M",
                   "spark.driver.memory": "38300M",
                   "spark.yarn.scheduler.reporterThread.maxFailures": "5",
                   "spark.driver.cores": "5",
                   "spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead": "4255M",
                   "spark.executor.heartbeatInterval": "60s",
                   "spark.rdd.compress": "true",
                   "spark.network.timeout": "800s",
                   "spark.executor.cores": "5",
                   "spark.memory.storageFraction": "0.27",
                   "spark.speculation": "true",
                   "spark.sql.shuffle.partitions": "200",
                   "spark.shuffle.spill.compress": "true",
                   "spark.shuffle.compress": "true",
                   "spark.storage.level": "MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER",
                   "spark.default.parallelism": "200",
                   "spark.serializer": "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer",
                   "spark.memory.fraction": "0.80",
                   "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions": "-XX:+UseG1GC   -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill -9 %p'",
                   "spark.executor.instances": "107",
                   "spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead": "4255M",
                   "spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled": "false",
                   "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions": "-XX:+UseG1GC  -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill -9 %p'"
                   },
                "configurations": []
            },
            {
                "classification": "yarn-site",
                "properties": {
                   "yarn.log-aggregation-enable": "true",
                   "yarn.nodemanager.pmem-check-enabled": "false",
                   "yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled": "false"
                },
                "configurations": []
            },
            {
                "classification": "spark",
                "properties": {
                   "maximizeResourceAllocation": "true",
                   "spark.sql.broadcastTimeout": "-1"
                 },
                 "configurations": []
            },
            {
                 "classification": "emrfs-site",
                 "properties": {
                     "fs.s3.threadpool.size": "50",
                     "fs.s3.maxConnections": "5000"
                  },
                  "configurations": []
            },
            {
                  "classification": "core-site",
                  "properties": {
                     "fs.s3.threadpool.size": "50",
                     "fs.s3.maxConnections": "5000"
                   },
                   "configurations": []
             }

    ]
```

The profiler jar is stored in s3 (`mybucket/profilers/jvm-profiler-1.0.0.jar`). While bootstrapping my core and master nodes, I run the following bootstrap script

```
     sudo mkdir -p /tmp
     aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/profilers/jvm-profiler-1.0.0.jar /tmp/
```

I submit my emr step as follows

```
       spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster --master=yarn ......(other parameters).........
       --conf spark.jars=/tmp/jvm-profiler-1.0.0.jar --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-javaagent:jvm-profiler-1.0.0.jar=reporter=com.uber.profiling.reporters.ConsoleOutputReporter,metricInterval=5000 --conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-javaagent:jvm-profiler-1.0.0.jar=reporter=com.uber.profiling.reporters.ConsoleOutputReporter,metricInterval=5000
```

But I am unable to see the profiling related output in the logs (checked both stdout and stderr logs for all containers). Is the parameter ignored ? Am I missing something ? Is there something else I could check to see why this parameter is being ignored ?

Comment: You do not need the bootstrap, spark-submit will read the s3 address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used Uber JVM Profiler but I think to add extra jars in `spark-submit` you should be using [`--jars`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html#adding-other-jars) option. And you can add them directly from S3 bucket when working on EMR.

Also, at bootstrap, you're copying the jar `jvm-profiler-1.0.0.jar` into `/tmp` folder but when you set Java options you didn't add the path. Try this :

```
 spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster \
 --master=yarn \
 --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-javaagent:/tmp/jvm-profiler-1.0.0.jar=reporter=com.uber.profiling.reporters.ConsoleOutputReporter,metricInterval=5000" \
 --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-javaagent:/tmp/jvm-profiler-1.0.0.jar=reporter=com.uber.profiling.reporters.ConsoleOutputReporter,metricInterval=5000" \
 --jars "/tmp/jvm-profiler-1.0.0.jar" \
 --<other params>
```

Comment: the above doesn't work either. Still not able to see any output in the logs.

Comment: Hemm, have you tried setting the full path in `javaagent` option? I guess `/tmp/` is a relative path.

Comment: I figured out my mistake. I was giving my application jar before these paramters, so these parameters were going into my application as arguments rather than spark. The above works.